# Merge columns from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling with this issue for the last day or so. I'm trying to merge multiple columns in a data frame that are grouped by email & store.

I currently have a data frame:

```
df = module.get("/test.xlsx"), format="excel"
```

Result:

| Email | Store | Order1 | Order2 | Order3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test@email.com | Location1 | 3457834 | 123434 | 345678 |
| test@email.com | Location2 | 4232234 | 123456 | 348902 |
| tes2t@email.com | Location3 | 2346442 | 123432 |  |

The only difference is the table goes from `Order1` to `Order20`

Desired outcome it to merge all Order numbers into a single column with a line break, and if the order number is null such as `Order3` on the last row then stop. There will never be a scenario where Order3 is null and orders 4-20 are not null. It's simply printed in order by the data source.

| Email | Store | Orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test@email.com | Location1 | 3457834\n123434\n345678 |
| test@email.com | Location2 | 4232234\n123456\n348902 |
| tes2t@email.com | Location3 | 2346442\n123432 |

Any help on how to start on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
df_orders = df.filter(like='Order')
df['Orders'] = df_orders.apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x[~x.isnull()].values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```